# ubuntu 14.04 server perl POSIX install error

Tags: perl, ubuntu, posix

I don't know perl, I just needed POSIX as a dependency for a script. I have configured cpan answering the default questions and then, inside cpan,

```
install POSIX
```

I have been asked a million questions, answered default to all, and now the script is installing a million modules. Do I really need this ? I'm concerned if something goes wrong is it possible to undo this easily ?

UPDATE

well, what I feared just happened

```
Everything is up to date. Type '/usr/bin/make test' to run test suite.
./perl -Ilib installperl --destdir=   
/usr/local/bin is not writable by you
make: ** [install-all] Erro 2
RJBS/perl-5.22.0.tar.bz2
/usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
RJBS/perl-5.22.0.tar.bz2                     : install NO
```

please, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Run `o conf init` and read the options very carefully. Specifically, the one about installation directory.

Comment: I have done this already I think, by typing cpan on shell. But I have answered the default to all questions. Should I do this again, even after failing to install the POSIX module ? Do I have to uninstall or rollback anything before ?

Comment: Don't answer default to all questions. Specifically, **read** the one about *local* installdir. You'll have a few options that you need to really pay attention to. Another is **uninst**. Anyway, the installation failed so you don't need to do anything to correct your previous attempt.

Comment: I ran the config again, it asks first if I want auto conf when possible. If I hit yes there is nothing to do, if I hit no he asks a lot of questions, but I can't find any one regarding installdir. Maybe I should remove my .cpan folder before reconfiguring ? Also, there is no way to do this automatically, like a default ubuntu configuration ? I really would rather not bother configuring pearl, just want to run a script.

Comment: Can I just run cpan as sudo so I will be able to write to /usr/local/bin ? No default answer to config is /usr/local/bin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX is a core module included with Perl. You don't need to install it separately. Why don't you just install Perl via your package manager instead of from source?

Comment: I thought I would go this way but pearl and cpan were already installed by default. When I tried to run the script it complained about the dependencies. What exactly is POSIX ?

Comment: Something isn't right. [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) has been a core module since Perl 5, which had its first release a looooooong time ago. Are you sure that POSIX is the missing dependency?

Comment: You are right, when I got the first dependency error I just started installing the list given by the script maker.